# Browserify + npm & dedupe - how to produce output files

Tags: npm, browserify

I'm investigating an approach to implement npm (with dedupe) as a dependency manager (instead of bower). And now, I have npm packages like jquery-ui that use CommonJS require statements to include dependencies like jquery.

Before using npm, I used reqular jquery-ui script, without require. So now I guess I have to use Browserify to generate JavaScript that can be used inside the browser.

And now I have a questions (let's consider jquery & jquery-ui example): if I have other packages (or my own code) that uses jQuery, does it mean I always must have one output file from Browserify? For instance: jquery-ui depends on jquery, and my own code also depends on jquery. If I have two separate output builds eg:

`browserify jquery-ui.js -o dist/jquery-ui.js
browserify myCode.js -o dist/myCode.js`

then this approach is bad, because I'll have two jquery included twice. Do I get it correctly?

Perhaps that is the question that summarizes everything: Do I need to have one application wide "main.js" file that requires everything that is needed for my application?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed.  You'll have to `npm dedupe` pre-browserify and use multiple entry points.  If you are browserifying twice, you'll package two versions of that module.  You may be best off building a partitioned bundle set.  In this regard, you can use one browserify command and not duplicate modules.  Check out the handbook here: https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#partitioning